# How to verify Google identity services's response

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, google-signin, google-identity, react-google-login

I'm trying to log user in with google and I'm using their Identity Services, I used the following code in client side.

```
google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id:
        "*********.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      callback: handleCallback,
    });
```

The response I get is extremely limited as in I get

1. clientId
2. credential
3. select_by

and after decoding the credentials I get basic user info with

1. nbf
2. aud
3. sub
4. azp
5. iat
6. jti

I have no idea what these are.
So when I send these information to my server, I can easily store them and generate a id to be sent back to the client to log them in using cookie. But when user logs out and logs back in how do I not make multiple entries in my server? How do I check in my database that the new user already has an account. I don't think I could match the incoming email address to the one stored in my database since that would be a security risk. How do I actually verify the request to my server?

Comment: You should send the `credential` to the server, use the `google-auth-library` library to verify the ID token. The payload of the decrypted token contains an email property. In your database, you check if a user already exist with that email address. If not, you create it first, then you set the cookie with the user id from your database.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it. Now that I know that "credential" is verified I can simply match the email address I got from the response and the one at my database right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read though [Verify id token](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) Depending upon which client library you are using there should be a method that you can call to verify it.

Java for example

```
GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
if (idToken != null) {
  Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

  // Print user identifier
  String userId = payload.getSubject();
  System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

  // Get profile information from payload
  String email = payload.getEmail();
  boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
  String name = (String) payload.get("name");
  String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
  String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
  String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
  String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
```

As for the claims have a look in the RFC [rfc7519#section-4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1)

- "sub" (Subject) Claim - Users google internal id
- "aud" (Audience) Claim  -  Who the token was intended for.
- "exp" (Expiration Time) Claim  - when it will expire
- "nbf" (Not Before) Claim   - when it was good from
- "iat" (Issued At) Claim  - when it was issued
- "jti" (JWT ID) Claim  - Id of this claimset.
- "azp". Authorized party - the party to which the ID Token was issued

Sub is your magic claim.  This will tell you the users internal google id so if you store this in your system along with the users account on your system. You will always be able to link them.   This is called account linking.